# How can it be seen that the Von Neumann universe $V_{\omega+\omega}$ does not model the Fraenkel axiom

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Consider the Von Neumann universe $V_{\omega+\omega}$. As mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) on Von Neumann universes, $(V_{\omega+\omega},\in)$ is a model for $\rm Z$, but not for the Fraenkel axiom of replacement.

How can it be seen this is not a model of this axiom? I have already followed the note on the Wiki page, but was not succesful in retrieving a proof of this fact.

Comment: Look at the function $f : \omega \to \omega + \omega$ defined by $f(n) = \omega + n$.

Comment: @Paul: That should have been an answer!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402271/von-neumann-universe-in-zc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the function $f : \omega \to \omega + \omega$ defined by $f(n) = \omega + n$.  This function is not a member of $V_{\omega + \omega}$, but it's definable using parameters from $V_{\omega + \omega}$, and its domain is in $V_{\omega + \omega}$.  Its range is not a member of $V_{\omega + \omega}$.

You can use this argument in more generality to show that, if $V_\alpha$ satisfies replacement, and $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha$ must be a regular cardinal.

**Edit**: As Asaf points out in the comments, the last line is false!  I'm leaving it there so that hopefully fewer people will make this mistake.

Comment: The last line is not true. The least $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models\sf ZFC$ has to be of countable cofinality. It's just that there is no $\varphi$ which defines a cofinal sequence inside $V_\alpha$. (See also [Worldly cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly).) What is true, however, is that if $V_\alpha$ satisfies the *second-order* variant of replacement (now a single axiom) then it is necessarily the case that $\alpha$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: Thanks Asaf, I knew I was saying something wrong, but I posted anyway.  At least now we have some more interesting stuff written here.