# Ordinal rank of inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Maybe this question is still confused:

By Powerset applied to any countable infinite set, $V_{\omega+2}$ contains sets of uncountable cardinality, which means that the least ordinal equinumerous with those sets is uncountable. But since the rank of an ordinal is equal to itself, the least uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ doesn't appear until much later in the hierarchy, namely, at $V_{\omega_1+1}$. How is this explained?

Also, given an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, what is the least rank of a set $A$ whose cardinality is $\kappa$?

Comment: I think there's some confusion here.  It's true that $V_{\omega + 2}$ contains sets of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, but the cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ itself, i.e. the least ordinal with that cardinality, is not one of them.  Its rank is $2^{\aleph_0}$; every ordinal has rank equal to itself.  So maybe what you want to ask is, given an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, what is the least rank of a set $A$ whose cardinality is $\kappa$?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Nate, I'll edit my question.

Comment: For your first question, it's unclear what you want explained.  Everything you've said is correct, and there's not really anything more to explain.

Comment: So is it that we know those sets to be uncountable by Cantor's theorem, but we can't give a constructive proof of their uncountability until we have the ordinals to compare them with?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a constructive proof of their uncountability".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The von Neumann hierarchy is very "wide", not very "tall". Namely, by taking power sets, we quickly rise in cardinality, but not in "depth" (which is what the notion of rank sort of models).

This is not a problem, and it's even kind of intuitive because for one, it also something that holds for the finite levels of the hierarchy. $V_4$ has an element of size $4$ (namely, $V_3$), but $4$ itself only appears in the next level. And things only get worse when you continue.

Now. Let's analyze something... define the following sequence of cardinals: $\alpha_0$ is an arbitrary fixed cardinal; $\alpha_{n+1}=|V_{\alpha_n}|$; and finally $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$. I claim that any $\eta<\alpha$ satisfies that $|V_\eta|<\alpha$. And indeed, if $\eta<\alpha$, then $\eta<\alpha_n$ for some $n$, and therefore $V_\eta\subseteq V_{\alpha_{n+1}}$. Therefore, the first time a set of size $\alpha$ appears is exactly $V_{\alpha+1}$, where $\alpha$ itself is also a member.

But we can say even more. We can give a complete characterizations of all the $\alpha$'s which satisfy the last property. These are exactly those $\alpha$ such that $\beth_\alpha=\alpha$ (recall the $\beth$ numbers are defined by taking power sets at successor levels and limits at limits). This requires some calculation, but it's a good exercise.

### Finally!

Where does that put us with inaccessible cardinals? If you mean *strongly* inaccessible, then $\kappa$ is a $\beth$ fixed-point, i.e. $\kappa=\beth_\kappa$, in which case $\kappa+1$ is the least rank of a set of size $\kappa$. But if we are only talking about *weakly* inaccessible cardinals, well, $2^{\aleph_0}$ can consistently be largrer than the least weakly inaccessible cardinals (in fact, it can be as big as we want), which would mean that $V_{\omega+2}$ already knows about some *very*, ***very*** large sets.

Comment: +1. A comment to the OP: re: Asaf's first paragraph, it might be helpful to think about theories weaker than ZF which have "short" universes - e.g. [Zermelo set theory Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402271/von-neumann-universe-in-zc), which proves that there are uncountable well-ordered sets but can't even prove that the ordinal $\omega+\omega$ exists! *(Note that that answer talks about ZC, Zermelo + choice, but choice isn't needed here.)*

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your first question, but here's an answer to your second question.  If $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then $|V_\alpha|<\kappa$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.  This is easy to prove by induction on $\alpha$: at successor steps you use the fact that $\kappa$ is strong limit and at limit steps you use the fact that $\kappa$ is regular.  In particular if $A$ is a set of rank $\alpha<\kappa$, then $A\subseteq V_\alpha$ and so $|A|<\kappa$.