# Existence of order types if we assume Choice in the metatheory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I am looking at Zermelo's 1930a proof that if $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, then $V_{\kappa}$ is a model of ZF. To show that Powerset holds he takes an arbitrary set $x \in V_\kappa$ and assumes that $x$ can be well-ordered in type $\sigma <$ $\kappa$, whereby $2^{|\sigma|} = \wp(X) < \kappa$. I don't understand why the assumption is true: why can't the order type of $x$ be greater than $\kappa$, hence outside the model, given that the proof of well-ordering is a proof in the metatheory.

More generally, my question is: if we are using ZFC to prove results about some transitive *set* model, then by Choice in the metatheory, every set in our model can be well-ordered. Those well-orderings need only exist in the metatheory and not necessarily in our model. So then does it follow that the order type of a set in our model is itself in the model?

Comment: What do you mean by "the order type of a set in our model", exactly?  In Zermelo's proof, I would imagine the statement "$x$ can be well-ordered in type $\sigma<\kappa$" is working outside the model, not in the model.

Comment: The question looks a bit awkward to read. I'd recommend revising it slightly: start with the context; explain why "the first assumption seems wrong" to you; then move on to the question.

Comment: Re the first paragraph: Which theory is the model required to satisfy?

Comment: Re the last paragraph: By "inaccessible" do you (& Zermelo) mean strongly inaccessible?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, here's an edit.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet In the case of Zermelo, he was (implicitly I think) using ZFC to prove results about models of ZF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\sigma<\kappa$ here isn't a general fact about transitive models; it's a consequence of the very special situation we are considering.  Specifically, $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, so every element of $V_\kappa$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$ (see, for instance, [my answer to an earlier question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2431355/86856)).  Therefore $x$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$, and therefore so does the order-type of any well-ordering of $x$.