# do we need transfinite recursion theorem and/or transfinit induction principle to define ordinals?

Tags: set-theory

I'm learning some about Set Theory of my own and I'm following the appendix of Kelley's *General Topology*. In his development, he constructs first the ordinals, and then the naturals and the cardinals. He never mentions Transfinite recursion theorem nor Transfinite induction principle for that construction (as far as I know).

On the other hand, Enderton's book *Elemntary of set theory* starts with natural numbers and then, in chapter 7, he introduces ordinal numbers. I think the background both constructions is the same, but I think Enderton takes more care. He presents the Transfinite Recursion Theorem and Transfinite induction principle before to start with the ordinal's construction.

I know that this is always a difficult question but... **what approach do you follow to learn about the constrction of naturals and ordinals**, Enderton or Kelley? Remember Kelley's theory is allowed to discuss classes, while Enderton's (ZFC) not. Does it matter for the construction?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need transfinite recursion (that is, the [replacement axiom scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement)) to *define* ordinals, but it's important to prove their basic properties - for example, [without it you can't even prove that $\omega+\omega$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402271/von-neumann-universe-in-zc)!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: So, do you think Enderton's approach is better? Or I should continue with Kelley's book?

Comment: @Dog_69 Depends on what you are aiming for. Kelley's outline is probably fine to get by with for most mathematicians. From Enderton, you can expect a more refined treatment of set theoretical ideas. Whether you allow classes or not doesn't matter for the theory of ordinals for your purposes.

Comment: @Stefan Mesken: Thank you very much. Nice comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered in comments.

Comment: Rather than close the question (answered in comments $\nRightarrow$ off-topic), I encourage you to write up an answer from your perspective as the OP.