# What is the formal way of constructing limit ordinals larger than $\omega$ (for example, $\omega + \omega$)?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to figure out how one constructs limit ordinals that are larger than $\omega$. In my book, the Axiom of Infinity (to create a set $X$ that contains the natural numbers) followed by the Separation / Comprehension Schema (with the formula $\varphi(n):= n \text{ is a natural number }$) is used to carve $\omega$ from $X$...the author calls this set $\omega$ the *least limit ordinal*.

I have read that, starting at $\omega$, you would (informally) apply the successor function an infinite number of times. This yields $S(\omega) = \omega \cup \{\omega\}=\omega+1$, $S(S(\omega))= \omega+1\  \cup \ \{\omega+1 \}=\omega+2$, etc.

Is the process as straightforward as defining the following set:

$T = \{ \omega + n\,|\, n\in \omega\}$

And then taking the union $\bigcup T$? (Knowing that such a union yields the *supremum* \ least upper bound of the set $T$)

---

If the above construction is the *standard* construction, then my once concern is, "**From which set am I selecting the $\omega + n$ elements**?".

The strategy I am familiar with is invoking the Separation / Comprehension schema to carve away subsets. But I think that must *not* be what I am doing above...because that would presuppose the existence of $\omega + \omega$ (or at least some ordinal that is larger than $\omega + \omega$).

**So what is the method that I am actually using to create $T$ in the first place?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that Separation doesn't do the job. Instead, this is exactly what the axiom (scheme) of [**Replacement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) does!

We first write down a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in two free variables which intuitively says "$y=\omega+x$." We then prove that for each $x\in\omega$ there is a unique $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$ holds - at which point Replacement lets us form $$\{y:\exists x\in\omega(\varphi(x,y))\}=\{\omega+n: n\in\omega\}.$$ Applying the Union axiom then finishes the job.

Meanwhile, to see that Separation won't suffice, it's a good exercise to check that $V_{\omega+\omega}\models\mathsf{ZC}$ (= the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms except Replacement). Since $\omega+\omega\not\in V_{\omega+\omega}$, this means that $\mathsf{ZC}$ alone can't prove that $\omega+\omega$ exists. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402289/28111) for further discussion of this point.)

Comment: Thank you! So the axiom of replacement is effectively required to create all such limit ordinals greater than $\omega$?

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes, that's exactly what the fact that $V_{\omega+\omega}\models\mathsf{ZC}$ indicates. (That said there are subtleties here: using powerset and separation we **can** in $\mathsf{ZC}$ prove the existence of well-orderings of ordertype $\omega+\omega$ and much more, we just can't construct the corresponding ordinals. See the link in the parenthetical comment at the end of my answer.)

Comment: Very cool. For confirmation (because the other answer provided uses language that seems to suggest something different from yours), $\{ \omega + n: n \in \omega \}=\bigcup \{\omega + n: n \in \omega \}$, right?

Comment: @S.Cramer Whoops, good catch - fixed!

Comment: That mistake is actually quite helpful, hah! I realize now that $\{\omega+n | n \in \omega \} \cup \omega = \bigcup \{\omega + n | n \in \omega \}$ !

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$ you construct by successively applying the successor function ordinals $\omega+n$ for each $n \in \omega$. Then the axiom of replacement tells us that

$$\{\omega+n \mid n \in \omega\}$$ is a set too and we can take its union (which order-theoretically is the sup) of that set to form $\omega+\omega$.

In that case it’s also enough to have one uncountable ordinal (which exists by power set and AC, or use Hartog’s trick) and note that all the above countable ordinals must be elements (and initial segments) of it, and apply separation. The way one goes about it depends on your text’s setup, I suppose.

Comment: Actually powerset and AC will not give you an uncountable ordinal. They'll give you an uncountable *well-ordering*, but that's much weaker. Replacement is needed to build $\omega+\omega$, since $V_{\omega+\omega}\models\mathsf{ZC}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber A subtlety, but you’re right of course. My first instinct was Replacement and then I wanted an alternative too..